# Equiping a vector space with a norm.

Tags: vector-spaces

Given an arbitrary vector space $V$ with a basis over an arbitary field $F$ is it possible to produce a norm on V? I know that if $V$ is a vector space with a basis over a field $K\subset \mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}$ then one can use $||\sum \alpha_i x_i||=\sum|\alpha_i|$ if the basis is finite and $||\sum \alpha_i x_i||=\max{\alpha_i}$ if the basis is infinite, but what about a field $F\not\subset \mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is impossible. Consider a field $F$ whose characteristic $\ne 0$, you can add up identical non-zero vectors to get a zero vector. This violates the subadditivity of norm.

Edit: I don't think the absolute homogeneity of norm is even well-defined (or definable) if $F$ is arbitrary, so...

Comment: Define $|x|=1$ for any scalar or vector $x\neq0$.

Comment: @mr_e_man That's a good point, thank you for pointing that out. I have totally forgotten that I answered this question. Apparently my knowledge was very limited at the time and I did not consider the possibility of defining the size of all nonzero scalars to be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @BigbearZzz is wrong. Actually, always it is possible to define a norm in a vector space even when the characteristic of the field is nonzero.
For more details, see my answer to a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2568231/113061

Comment: For some reason I managed to stumble upon this question again today after so many years. Thank you for correcting me, back then I had never heard of valuation over finite fields before. It is indeed an interesting concept.